# How to put numbers in parenthesis using cleveref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref

I am using the cleveref package for cross-referencing. When I use

> \cref{tab1} and \cref{fig1}

I got the output as

> table 1 and fig. 1

respectively. I would instead like to get

> table (1) and fig. (1)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the default format using `\crefdefaultlabelformat`; in your case, you can use

```
\crefdefaultlabelformat{(#2#1#3)}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefdefaultlabelformat{(#2#1#3)}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
A
\caption{a test table}
\label{tab:test}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
\centering
B
\caption{a test figure}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\cref{tab:test} and~\cref{fig:test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The above solution will affect all references produced by `cleveref`; if you want to affect just those for `figure` and `table`, use `\creflabelformat`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\creflabelformat{figure}{(#2#1#3)}
\creflabelformat{table}{(#2#1#3)}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
A
\caption{a test table}
\label{tab:test}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
\centering
B
\caption{a test figure}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\cref{tab:test} and~\cref{fig:test}

\end{document}
```